# How to use date time precision gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date-format

I'm trying to allow a user to input a date in a very permissive format (e.g. year only, year & month, or exact date). The [date_time_precision](https://github.com/Spokeo/date_time_precision) gem seems perfect, but I'm a newbie and I can't figure out (beyond installing the gem) how to get my form to allow these various levels of precision (I've read the readme several times).

I'm using the simple_form gem with the following in the date portion of my _form:

```
<%= f.input :date, 
            :include_blank => true, 
            as: :string, 
            order: [ :year, :month, :day,], 
            hint: 'Order: Year, month, date' %>
```

The documentation has a heading called 'Usage', and then...

```
require 'date_time_precision'
```

But I can't figure out where to put that. Does it go somewhere in my controller?

### Further info:

I did all the usual stuff (added gem to gemfile, bundle install, restart server, and refresh form page).

### Updates:

My form seems pretty much broken now, I keep getting errors like "ActionController::ActionControllerError in ArtworksController#update
Cannot redirect to nil!"

My routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "pages#home"

  get "artworks" => "artworks#index"
  # post "artworks" => "artworks#index"

  resources :artworks #, path: ''

  get "about" => "pages#about"
end
```

My controller:

```
    class ArtworksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_artwork, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /artworks
  # GET /artworks.json
  def index
    @artworks = Artwork.all
  end

  # GET /artworks/1
  # GET /artworks/1.json
  def show
    @artwork = Artwork.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if request.path != artwork_path(@artwork)
      redirect_to @artwork, status: :moved_permanently
    end
  end

  # GET /artworks/new
  def new
    @artwork = Artwork.new
  end

  # GET /artworks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /artworks
  # POST /artworks.json
  def create
    @artwork = Artwork.new( artwork_params )

    respond_to do |format|
      if @artwork.save
        format.html { redirect_to @artwork, notice: 'Artwork was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @artwork }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @artwork.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /artworks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /artworks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @artwork.update(artwork_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @artworks, notice: 'Artwork was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @artwork }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @artwork.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /artworks/1
  # DELETE /artworks/1.json
  def destroy
    @artwork.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to artworks_url, notice: 'Artwork was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_artwork
      @artwork = Artwork.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def artwork_params
      params.require(:artwork).permit(:title, :image, :genre, :category, :medium, :slug, :availability, :date, :height, :width)
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you put it in Gemfile?

Comment: Yes, and bundle installed.

Comment: And restart a server after `bundle install`?

Comment: Yep, shut 'er down and started up again, refresh page, redo form and I'm still getting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is desirable to manipulate dates or times for which incomplete information is known. For example, one might only know the year, or the year and the month. Unfortunately, Ruby's built-in Date, Time, and Date Time classes do not keep track of the precision of the data. 
In above regard, the [date_time_precision gem](https://github.com/Spokeo/date_time_precision) is used. Just to provide your helper methods to complete the date/time objects.

Your Case : 
In your case in your view you need a date picker / time date picker(for a better use experience). 
I would suggest  go with [bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails)

```
Instructions are clearly stated in the github link : 
 1. Install Gem. 
 2. Mark the related js files required in your application.js file.
 3. Add your datepicker / datetimepicker to a specific class (in document ready block)
 4. Use the datetimepicker in your View.
```

Comment: Ajay, thanks for the link, but in my case I actually don't want a calendar to choose from. For example, when I type "Dec 2013" in the [example link](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox), it forces an exact date — precisely what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The [date_time_precision](https://github.com/Spokeo/date_time_precision) library extends Ruby's [Date](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) and [Time](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html) classes to have a `precision` attribute which tracks if only the year is known, only the year and month, or the year, month, and day.

First, [install the library as a gem](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-install) with this:

```
gem install date_time_precision
```

Then, this code should work for you:

```
require 'date_time_precision'
def Date.parse_fuzzy(str)
  if /\A\s*(\d{4})\s*\z/ =~ str
    Date.new($1.to_i)
  else
    Date.parse(str)
  end
end
```

That's just an extension of [Date.parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) that can also accept standalone years. Enjoy!